# Loader Manager on API level 8 and above

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Im trying to build a list view with contacts. I came across the ContactManager API sample that uses ContactsContract and managed query to retrieve contacts. However the API recommends to use LoaderManager if I'm targeting API level 11 and above. My question is that how can I use the LoaderManager on API Level 8 with ActionBarSherlock ? or is it simply allrite to use managed query on API level 11 and above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is that how can I use the LoaderManager on API Level 8 with ActionBarSherlock ?

The `FragmentActivity` from the Android Support package offers a backport of the `Loader` framework. Since ActionBarSherlock also uses this Android Support package, any of your activities that inherit from `SherlockFragmentActivity` will also be able to use the `Loader` framework.

> or is it simply allrite to use managed query on API level 11 and above?

The problem with `managedQuery()` is that it performs the query on the main application thread, which can lead to a frozen UI. If you do not wish to use `Loaders`, that's fine, but then do the queries yourself, using a `ContentResolver`, in an `AsyncTask` or other background thread.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. Now my contacts retrieving logic is similar to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html How can I call this from the SherlockFragmentActivity ?

Comment: @Jani: Call `getSupportLoaderManager()` to get a `LoaderManager`.

Comment: Got it :) but what if I would want to have a ListFragment like on the link provided and call that fragment from the SherlockFragmentActivity  ?. I assume that if I handle the listview from the SherlockFragmentActivity I would need to handle the list manually. I apologize for any confusions as I'm totally new to fragments

Comment: @Jani: You would have your `SherlockFragmentActivity` host a `SherlockListFragment`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, can you give a little code example, I'm having the same issue. Thanks